# Зачем в html верстке классов применяются разные форматы имен классов?

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка, классы

Во многих проектах я видел разные имена классов элементов. Встречал разделенные пробелами(`header logo`), двумя андерлайнами(`header__logo`) и знаком тире(`header-logo`).
В чем их разница? Это как-то стандартизированно?

Comment: Первое это два разных класса. Остальное это скорее всего вариации на тему БЭМ https://ru.bem.info/methodology/naming-convention/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да это методология BEM,

```
# Это основной блок
.elem {} 

# Дочерний блок
.elem__desc {}

# Изменяемое поведение
.elem--hide {}
```

Рекомендую ознакомиться со [статьей на CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/).